# Array with configured index does not work on ng-repeat nor display in html in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to `ng-repeat` a configured `$index` of an array, but this seems to not work in my favor.

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
let vm = this;
let obj = [
    {
       id: '12345-6789-10',
       code: 'test1',
       time_stamp: 15183626121
    }, {
       id: '12345-6789-11',
       code: 'test2',
       time_stamp: 15183626122
    }
];

vm.stocks_code = [];
obj.map(r => stocks_code[r.id] = r.code);
console.log(vm.stocks_code) // OUTPUT: [12345-6789-10: "test1",
                            //          12345-6789-11: "test2"];

let test = [12345-6789-10: "test1", 12345-6789-11: "test2"] // obviously wont
                             // work because only `{}` can handles this syntax.
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<pre>
   {{ vm.stocks | json }} // does not display
</pre>

<div ng-repeat="o in vm.stocks_code">
    {{ $index }} : {{ o }} // does not display
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use an array to store named properties, instead of an object? And why don't you use the syntax necessary to display the named properties of an object? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

Comment: I created a directive that sends back the id to the controller. Its also because lot of work is needed since I am gonna be using this method a lot.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that. The id is in the objects in the array. If you want to display the IDs and the code, all you need is `<div ng-repeat="o in vm.obj">
    {{ o.id }} : {{ o.code }}
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ng-repeat`:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.objArr = [
        {
           id: '12345-6789-10',
           code: 'test1',
           time_stamp: 15183626121
        }, {
           id: '12345-6789-11',
           code: 'test2',
           time_stamp: 15183626122
        }
    ];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
<div ng-repeat="o in vm.objArr">
    {{ $index }} : {{ o.id }}  {{o.code}}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using NG-REPEAT and displaying the $index is still 0 incrementing by 1 and not displaying the ID instead.

Comment: @AlwinHilario I repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties